# How to integrate Stripe "Pay with Card" in backbonejs

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe "Pay with Card" checkout into backbone Node environment. On the server side, I am using Stripe Node code - that part works good. However, on the client side, I am unable to capture the event.

**I would like to capture the submit event from the Stripe popup to call "paymentcharge" method in the view.**

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Stripe Payments Form Template -->
<form id="stripepaymentform" class="paymentformclass">
   <script
       src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
       data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
       data-amount="0299"
       data-name="MyDemo"
       data-description="charge for something"
       data-image="assets\ico\icon-72.png">
   </script>
</form>
```

Backbone View Class

```
myprog.PaymentPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    }, 
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    events : {
        "submit" : "paymentcharge"
    },
    paymentcharge : function( event) {
        this.model.set({stripeToken: stripeToken});
    } 
});
```

Backbone Model Class

```
var PaymentChargeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){
        return '/api/paymentcharge';
    },
    defaults: {
    }
})
```

Setup/Call the View from header menu event

```
if (!this.paymentPanelView) {
    this.paymentPanelView = new PaymentPanelView({model: new PaymentChargeModel()});
}
$('#content').html(this.paymentPanelView.el);   
this.paymentPanelView.delegateEvents();
this.selectMenuItem('payment-menu');
```

Comment: You may want to check out [**`backbone-stripe`**](https://github.com/amccloud/backbone-stripe), a `Backbone.Model` wrapper around stripe.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with your View's `el` and the event you are listening for.

You never explicitly define your View's `el`, which means it gets initialized to a detached `<div>` element. You then use your template to fill that `<div>` with the form element from the template. Even though your `<div>` is detached, you get to see the content, because you add the content of you `el` to `#content` using jquery.

I think the problem is that you are listening for a `submit` event on the `<div>` in your `el`, not the contained `<form>`. Try changing your events hash to this:

```
events: {
    'submit form#stripepaymentform': 'paymentcharge'
}
```

Basically, listen for events on the contained element like in jquery's `.on`. You can also go right to a button click, something like this:

```
'click #mysubmitbutton': 'paymentcharge'
```

Hope this helps!